# Android camera settings missing when launched by an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera-intent

When I launch the camera app manually, I have access to the settings for things like white balance, scale, resolution etc (via icons on the left hand side of the screen). However when I launch the camera via an intent these option icons are not visible:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.SET_CUSTOM_PHOTO_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Is there any way to make the camera settings available when the camera is launched from an intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to make the camera settings available when the camera is launched from an intent?

The decision of what the UI will be, for the activity that responds to that `Intent`, is up to the authors of that app. There are hundreds of pre-installed camera apps and countless more available for download from the Play Store and elsewhere. Any of them could be handling your request.

There is nothing documented in the protocol for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` that allows you to request changes to the camera UI, and there is no law on the books anywhere that would force the camera app developers to honor it even if there were.